# how to change column after n rows while inserting values from array to excel cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

can you please guide how to put array values in multiple columns like first four values in first column , than 5 values in second column, and than may be 2 in second column….. and so on. i tried do while loop and for loop but the results are not satisfactory ————————-

```
    Sub PickNamesAtRandom()
Dim HowMany As Long
Dim NoOfNames As Long
Dim RandomColumn As Integer
Dim RandomRow As Integer
Dim Names() As String ‘Array to store randomly selected names
Dim i As Byte
Dim CellsOutRow As Integer
Dim CellsOutColumn As Integer ‘Variable to be used when entering names onto worksheet
Dim ArI As Byte ‘Variable to increment through array indexes

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
HowMany = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets(“test”).Range(“A2:E2”))
CellsOutRow = 3
CellsOutColumn = 1
ReDim Names(1 To HowMany) ‘Set the array size to how many names required
NoOfNames = Application.CountA(Sheets(“sheet1”).Range(“D4:L45”)) ‘ Find how many names in the list
i = 1
Do While i <= HowMany
RandomNo:
RandomRow = Application.RandBetween(1, 45)
RandomColumn = Application.RandBetween(1, 15)
'Check to see if the name has already been picked
For ArI = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
If Names(ArI) = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(RandomRow, RandomColumn).Value Then
GoTo RandomNo
End If
Next ArI
Names(i) = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(RandomRow, RandomColumn).Value ' Assign random name to the array
i = i + 1
Loop
Dim RequiredRows As Integer
RequiredRow = 2
'Loop through the array and enter names onto the worksheet
For ArI = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)

Do
Cells(CellsOutRow, CellsOutColumn) = Names(ArI)
CellsOutRow = CellsOutRow + 1
Loop While CellsOutRow < Cells(RequiredRow, CellsOutColumn).Value
CellsOutColumn = CellsOutColumn + 1
Next ArI
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For our sake and your own, please *indent* code when posting, otherwise it's pretty difficult to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub WriteValues(ByVal values As Collection)

    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim val As Variant
    
    row = 1
    
    For Each val In values
    
        Select Case row
    
            ' first four values in first column
            Case Is <= 4
                col = 1
    
            ' than 5 values in second column,
            Case Is <= 9
                col = 2
    
            ' and than may be 2 in second column...
            Case Is <= 11
                col = 2
    
            ' row > 11
            Case Else
                col = 3
    
        End Select
    
        Cells(row, col).Value = val
        
        row = row + 1
    
    Next val

End Sub
```